# How to convert DataFrame to Json?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge JSON file, a small part from it as follows:

```
{
    "socialNews": [{
        "adminTagIds": "",
        "fileIds": "",
        "departmentTagIds": "",
        ........
        ........
        "comments": [{
            "commentId": "",
            "newsId": "",
            "entityId": "",
            ....
            ....
        }]
    }]
    .....
    }
```

I have applied lateral view explode on socialNews as follows:

```
val rdd = sqlContext.jsonFile("file:///home/ashish/test")
rdd.registerTempTable("social")
val result = sqlContext.sql("select * from social LATERAL VIEW explode(socialNews) social AS comment")
```

Now I want to convert back this result (DataFrame) to JSON and save into a file, but I am not able to find any Scala API to do the conversion.
Is there any standard library to do this or some way to figure it out?

Answer (score 35):

```
val result: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(path)
result.write.json("/yourPath")
```

The method `write` is in the class [DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) and should be accessible to you on `DataFrame` objects. Just make sure that your rdd is of type `DataFrame` and not of deprecated type `SchemaRdd`. You can explicitly provide type definition `val data: DataFrame` or cast to dataFrame with `toDF()`.

Answer (score 32):

If you have a DataFrame there is an API to convert back to an RDD[String] that contains the json records.

```scala
val df = Seq((2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7), (2012, 7, "Robot", 5.5), (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0)).toDF("year", "month", "title", "rating")
df.toJSON.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/jsonRecords")
df.toJSON.take(2).foreach(println)
```

This should be available from Spark 1.4 onward. Call the API on the result DataFrame you created.

The APIs available are listed [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

Comment: I got could-not-find-class exception

Comment: What version of Spark and distro are you using?

Answer (score 5):

```
sqlContext.read().json(dataFrame.toJSON())
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run your spark job as 
`--master local --deploy-mode client`
Then, 
`df.write.json('path/to/file/data.json')` works.

If you run on cluster [on header node], [`--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`] better approach is to write data to aws s3 or azure blob and read from it.

`df.write.json('s3://bucket/path/to/file/data.json')` works.

Answer (score -2):

If you still can't figure out a way to convert Dataframe into JSON, you can use to_json or toJSON inbuilt Spark functions.

Let me know if you have a sample Dataframe and a format of JSON to convert.