# How to parse rows of a small DataFrame as json strings?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame `df` is the result of some pre-processing. The size of `df` is around 10,000 rows.
I save this DataFrame in CSV as follows:
    `df.coalesce(1).write.option("sep",";").option("header","true").csv("output/path")`

Now I want to save this DataFrame as `txt` file in which is row is a JSON string. So, the column names should be passed to attributes in JSON strings.

For example:

```
df =
  col1   col2   col3
  aa     34     55
  bb     13     77

json_txt =
{"col1": "aa", "col2": "34", "col3": "55"}
{"col1": "bb", "col2": "13", "col3": "77"}
```

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: you can just use df.write.json(path to output)

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33701112/8932998) instead of .`toDF()` use `.createDataFrame()`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Will it write each row as I showed?

Comment: yes of course . try it , test it and if failed then let me know

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Let me test it to check if I get what I want simply using `df.coalesce(1).write.json("path")`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: yes, it works exactly as I expected. So simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `write.json` api to save a `dataframe` in `json` format as

```
df.coalesce(1).write.json("output path of json file")
```

Above code would create a *json* file. But if you want a *text* format (*json text*) then you can use `toJSON` api as

```
df.toJSON.rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("output path to text file")
```

I hope the answer is helpful