# pyspark.sql to JSON

Tags: json, pyspark

What's the best way to get a valid json document from pyspark.sql query.
For example, if I run:

```
spark.sql("show tables")
```

I see that it returns a dataframe and I can call 'toJSON' on that to get an RDD. But I'm not able to find a good way to convert that into a json document. I called 'collect()' on it, but that doesn't return a valid json and does not seem to be the most efficient way to convert dataframe to json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the json response using the method below:

```
def exec_spark_sql_query(query):
    json_rdd = spark.sql(query).toJSON()
    rdd_list = json_rdd.collect()
    output_json = ''
    for i, entry in enumerate(rdd_list):
        if (i == 0):
            output_json = output_json + '['
        if (i == len(rdd_list) - 1):
            return (output_json + entry + ']')
        output_json = output_json + entry + ','
    return output_json
```

I know this is definitely not the best way to get json response for a Python API call that executes an SQL query using SparkSQL, but this gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to write the JSON RDD as text files. The JSON will be correctly formatted.

`df.toJSON().saveAsTextFile("/tmp/jsonRecords")`

Note that this will write one file per partition. So there will be a need to concatenate them manually.

The approach is adapted from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473215/how-to-convert-dataframe-to-json), which uses Scala.

Comment: thanks, is there a more efficient way to do this? The reason is I'm doing this to process an api response so the response time matters and writing and reading from file will take longer.

Comment: In this case, it may be better to work directly with the JSON RDD given by `toJSON()`, and do your processing directly on them. JSON RDD is in JSON line format, which is easier to be handled for distributed processing in Spark. If you can edit your question to include a reproducible example with the processing you need, I can take further look into it.

Comment: thanks for the response, I wanted to let you know I got the json using the method I posted in answer below.